# How to mutate across a dataframe using dynamic dimension references?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Suppose we start with the `data` dataframe shown below, with the generating code immediately beneath:

```
> data
   To A  B  C
1   A 1  3  5
2   B 2  4  6
3   C 4  5  7
4 Sum 7 12 18
   
library(dplyr)
data <- 
   data.frame(
     To = c("A","B","C"),
     A = c(1,2,4),
     B = c(3,4,5),
     C = c(5,6,7)
   ) %>% 
   bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
```

I've been running the following bit of code to change the values in a dataframe much like it into percentages (each cell calculated as a % of its respective column "Sum"):

```
data %>% mutate(across(-1, ~ ./.[To == "Sum"]))
```

Giving the correct output of :

```
> data 
   To         A         B         C
1   A 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.2777778
2   B 0.2857143 0.3333333 0.3333333
3   C 0.5714286 0.4166667 0.3888889
4 Sum 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

How would the divisor of `[To == "Sum"]` in the `mutate(across...))` be swapped with a dynamic (perhaps numeric) reference to the last row of the dataframe instead? In the fuller code this is deployed in the dataframe dynamically and reactively expands/contracts based on user input into Shiny, and column header names also change dynamically so the fixed reference to the "To" header name in this example isn't optimal.

A brief explanation would be helpful too, so I don't have to keep coming to the trough for solutions.

Comment: @akrun's answer is correct but it's not very idiomatic in R to have a sum row in a data frame, so you are going to end up doing something a little awkward. It would be better to just have a data frame of values, create a separate dataframe of sums to use for operations, and if you need to present them in a table then bind them but only for presentation, not calculation.

Comment: @SamR An easier option is `janitor::adorn_totals(data)`

Comment: SamR your point is well taken. I've already encountered a disadvantage to appending the sum row to the dataframe. I now need to back that sum row out of the dataframe for converting to long format and it's getting messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `last` function to return the last value of the column.  Also, there is another option with `nth` where we can get the value of the column based on the index which is more general i.e. `nth(., 2)` returns the 2nd value

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
   mutate(across(-1, ~ ./last(.)))
```

-output

```
 To         A         B         C
1   A 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.2777778
2   B 0.2857143 0.3333333 0.3333333
3   C 0.5714286 0.4166667 0.3888889
4 Sum 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: This was one was too easy for you akrun! You deserve a break now and then with junior questions like these! Thank you for the explanation. I'll need to work through some intro materials for dplyr and data.table soon

Comment: Too easy for master akrun!

Answer (score 3):

Try this: It is more or less what akrun already is presenting:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    To = c("A","B","C"),
    A = c(1,2,4),
    B = c(3,4,5),
    C = c(5,6,7)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(across(-1, ~ ./sum(.))) %>% 
  bind_rows(summarise_all(., ~(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Sum")))
```

```
   To         A         B         C
1   A 0.1428571 0.2500000 0.2777778
2   B 0.2857143 0.3333333 0.3333333
3   C 0.5714286 0.4166667 0.3888889
4 Sum 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

in Base R you could do something like:

```
addmargins(prop.table(as.matrix(data.frame(data, row.names = 1)),2),1)

            A         B         C
A   0.1428571 0.2500000 0.2777778
B   0.2857143 0.3333333 0.3333333
C   0.5714286 0.4166667 0.3888889
Sum 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```